# What happens when the gwt.xml does not have <source> tags in it?

Tags: gwt

What is the default behaviour of the gwt java2js compiler if i do not specify in my gwt.xml something like  `<source path='insertname4folder'/>` . I have seen some multi-module projects that do not use these tags and i can only tell that a class will be translated only because it is in a X.client.Y package; i assume the j2js compiler  uses that convention by default too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It assumes the default folder as named "**client**" which is parallel to module.gwt.xml file.

Example:

```
Location of module xml file - com.insanity.examples.gwt.HelloWorld.gwt.xml 
Location of default gwt client code - com.insanity.examples.gwt.client
```

**That is as good as having  tag in the .gwt.xml file.**

You can read more about it here - http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModules

Comment: But it will also check  com.insanity.examples.gwt.client.* right?

Comment: Yes. All files under package and subpackages of com.insanity.examples.gwt.client are considered as JAVAScript compatible code.